# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'?

Tags: python-2.7, model, anaconda, hidden-markov-models, dimensionality-reduction

I am following some tutorials for the implementation of TICA, to do a dimension reduction, but I have the following problem;

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
np.bool was a deprecated alias for the builtin bool. To avoid this error in existing code, use bool by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use np.bool_ here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

I've already updated numpy, but I still get the same error.

What could I do?

I've already updated numpy, and I have create a entorn in conda, but I still get the same error.

What could I do?

Comment: Don't use `np.bool`, just use regular Python `bool`

Comment: I only imported numpy as np, but within the code I have not used np.bool.

Comment: Then you might need to downgrade NumPy as it seems one of the other libraries is using this. Try installing an old version of NumPy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is my code :   tica = pyemma.coordinates.tica(data, dim=1, lag=1)
tica_output = tica.get_output()
print(tica_output)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is to downgrade numpy, this worked for me

```
python -m pip install numpy==1.23.1
```